# It's possible to have transactions (in terms of data consistency) without ACID databases?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, acid

I'm working on a project with NodeJS, Kafka and Elasticsearch stack. We have an account microservice that needs to ensure data consistency of accounts balance and transactions (balance can only be negative for certain customers).

Thinking that we don't need results of transactions to be in real time, every operation can be processed asynchronous and later the results are shown to customer, there are some model (such as event-sourcing, CQRS) that provides data consistency of transactions without an ACID database?

If the model is just a lot of headache to do what ACID databases already do (and do well), we'll implement a SQL database (PostgreSQL) to fit this cases.

Answer (score 4):

This is not what Elasticsearch was created for. Although you can use transactions and locking to certain extent it will stay "eventually consistent" database

You can check following links to get an idea what is available in elasticsearch:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/versioning

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/concurrency-solutions.html

https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/transactional-acid-features-in-es/5357/2

Use case of [versioning](https://www.elastic.co/blog/versioning):

Let say we need to update resource from different workers. Common approach would be to:

1. read resource and get it's version number
2. prepare request to update resource using read version number in url
3. execute query

   - if no error -- we done
   - if we have error goto 1

In case of race condition only first service will execute the request without an error. Other competitors will have to try until they succeed.
Elasticsearch guarantees consistency on this kind of transactions.

example:

```
# creating the resource, take a look on _version field
# POST test/resources/42
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "resources",
  "_id": "42",
  "_version": 1,
  "result": "created",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "created": true
}

# reading the resource    
# GET test/resources/1
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "resources",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "value": 1
  }
}

# service number 1 trying to update the resource using version in url
# POST test/resources/1?version=1
# {...} 
# response has new version
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "resources",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 2,
  "result": "updated",
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "created": false
}

# service number 1 trying to update the resource -- fails
# POST test/resources/1?version=1
# {...}
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[resources][1]: version conflict, current version [2] is different than the one provided [1]",
        "index_uuid": "nQcwn90wQ9WauH9ySC7qEw",
        "shard": "3",
        "index": "test"
      }
    ],
    "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
    "reason": "[resources][1]: version conflict, current version [2] is different than the one provided [1]",
    "index_uuid": "nQcwn90wQ9WauH9ySC7qEw",
    "shard": "3",
    "index": "test"
  },
  "status": 409
}
```

Comment: Okay, I don't pretend to use only Elasticsearch to ensure data consistency, my question is about transaction model using the stack of the project, to be more generic, transactions in distributed data systems. Sorry for not pointing this in the original question. Using event-sourcing model can I have data consistency without an ACID database (the software was build on a microservice achitecture)?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think you could take a look on versioning functionality https://www.elastic.co/blog/versioning We use it for distributed messages and queues

Comment: This is a really amazing feature and clearly solves the problem of concurrent operations. But are the versions of a document visible immediately after the update or depend on the update operation on the indexes? I'm also wondering if it's really worth implementing a terse system in the case of version conflict (and how efficient it would be) or is it just adding cost to the project in relation to using a SQL database.

Comment: put more detailed example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do [transactional processing in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) ([vid](https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-london18/dont-repeat-yourself-introducing-exactly-once-semantics-in-apache-kafka)), and you can also land the data idempotently to Elastic using the [kafka-connect-elasticseach](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html#quick-start) connector ([more info](https://speakerdeck.com/rmoff/building-streaming-data-pipelines-with-elasticsearch-apache-kafka-and-ksql)).

Comment: Cool, I'm using librdkafka (Blizzard connection to NodeJS) that still does not implement EOS features. But in my case, imagine that I need to validate whether a monetary transaction can be made on top of a balance that can only be positive. In the case, I believe it will not be possible even without a relational database, since in Elasticsearch I depend on a refresh in the index to have the data visible for all queries. This really looks impossible without ACID databases.